# Exceptions to Fermat's Little Theorem [SOLVED]

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For the proof of Fermat's Little Theorem, it ends up being that

$(p-1)!\cdot a^{(p-1)} \equiv (p-1)!\pmod{p}$
then since $p ∤ (p-1)!$ when $p$ is prime

$a^{(p-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$

(as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536229/why-need-prime-number-in-fermats-little-theorem))

I understand why $p ∤ (p-1)!$ when $p$ is prime and why it fails when $p$ is composite, however, there exists (the only?) exception which is $4$. (as $4 ∤ 3!$)

So then why is it that Fermat's Little Theorem doesn't work when $p = 4$ and $(a,4) = 1?$

i.e. why is $7^{(4-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ not true, despite it satisfying the conditions of the proof

Thank you

(Apologies if it is just something stupid that I have overlooked)

Comment: 4 is not a prime number.

Comment: @Aaron I am aware, the point I'm making is that it is implied p has to be prime, so that p does not divide (p-1)!, however 4 has this property while not being prime, so why is it that it does not work when p=4

Comment: You have that the very last line of the proof would work when p=4, but what about all of the other lines in the proof?

Comment: @Aaron Copied:  Consider the reduced residue system modulo p, where p is prime. It's {1,2,…p−1}. Multiply all numbers by a, s.t. gcd(a,p)=1. Then we obtain the set {a,2a,…(p−1)a}. We'll prove that this set also represent the reduced residue system modulo p. It's enough to show that the numbers are unique modulo p. If we have that na≡ma(modp). Then we have that p∣(n−m)a⟹p∣(n−m), by Euclid's Lemma as gcd(a,p)=1. But obviously |n−m|≤p−1 so we must have n=m. Now multiplying all elements from the two reduced residue systems we have:

(p−1)!≡a⋅2a⋯(p−1)a≡ap−1(p−1)!(modp)⟹ap−1≡1(modp)

Comment: @Aaron that is copied and pasted from the second answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536229/why-need-prime-number-in-fermats-little-theorem

Comment: The linked proof breaks in multiple places when $p$ is composite: we need $a$ coprime to $p$ for $x\to ax$ to be a bijection mod $p$, and we need to restrict the residues to those coprime to $p$ if we want their product to be coprime to $p$ (so cancellable). Doing so generalizes the argument to a  proof of **Euler's Theorem** $\,a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod{\!n}\,$ if $a$ is coprime to $n.\ \ $

Comment: Actually, looking closer, the last line of the proof doesn't work here.  Yes, it is true that 4 does not divide 3!, but 3! is not invertible mod 4, because 3! is not relatively prime to 4.  So you can't divide both sides by 3!.

Comment: @aaron Thank you very much, I overlooked that

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you

Comment: Only the integers that are coprime with $n$ are invertible mod $n$, and $(n-1)!$ is coprime with $n$ if and only if $n$ is prime (or $1$). So for a non-prime an identity $(n-1)!a^{n-1}\equiv (n-1)!\pmod n$ implies that $a^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod{\frac n{\operatorname{gcd}(n,(n-1)!)}}$ which is a weaker condition than $a^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod n$. For instance, for $n=4$ you just obtain that $a^3\equiv 1\pmod 2$ for all odd integers, which incidentally is also true: for instance, $3^3\equiv -1\pmod 4$. Unfortunately it isn't quite the assertion you where expecting mod $4$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thank you very much

Comment: Note: if you know group theory then you can view this as a special case of Lagrange's Theorem, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1054852/242) (also mentioned in a deleted answer). Similarly for Wilson's theorem, e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1865/242).

Comment: Since the generalized proof mentioned in my prior comment has already been posted, I am closing this as a dupe of that. Someone might like to add a clearer complete proof there.